# How to re-run loader whenever data changed DB by a service

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to re-run the Loader to update Adapter data whenever data updated in DB from Service?

**DataPullService :**

```
public class DataPullService extends Service {


    private Timer nstimer=new Timer();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        NetworkConnection network=new NetworkConnection(this.getApplicationContext());
        boolean online = network.isOnline();
        if(online){
            try {
                nstimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        SQLiteDatabase mydb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                        values.put(DBConstants.COMPANY, "Innodea");

                        mydb.insert(DBConstants.FAVORITE_TABLE, null, values);

                    }
                }, 0, 60000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
          }
        }
        return startId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        nstimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

**MyListFragment:**

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setEmptyText("List loading...");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null, new String[]{DBConstants.SNO,DBConstants.COMPANY}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(getActivity());
        return new LiveMyLoader(getActivity(),dbHelper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(c);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


}
```

The above code load data when fragment created.Then how to update this list fragment whenever data changed in DB(updated by DataPullService)?

Answer (score 1):

I have added a BroadcastReceiver in MyListFragment and in onReceive method restarted Loader.

**In MyListFragment-onActivityCreated:**

```
mycontext=this;
getActivity().registerReceiver(FragmentReceiver1, new IntentFilter("fragmentupdater"));
```

**In MyListFragment**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver FragmentReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, mycontext);
            Log.i("timer", "Broadcast received");
        }};
```

**In MyListFragment-onDestroyView:**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(FragmentReceiver1);


}
```

**In DataPullService:**

```
Intent intent=new Intent("fragmentupdater");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now Whenever service updates data in DB, the broadscast receiver received and restart loader.

Note: Register receiver in Android manifest file.

Comment: Is this method is correct? i read in some pages,that said dont use fragment context in broadcast receiver?

Comment: I like this if it work because it means I don't need to make some kind of hard connection between the components.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to refresh data, call `getLoaderManager().restartLoader()` on your Loader. `restartLoader` will trigger `onCreateLoader` to be called again.In this case it will load new data.

Comment: Yes,how to call getLoaderManager from Service.getLoaderManager available in Activity and fragments only

Comment: Yes,how to restart Loader from Service

Answer (score 0):

1 Create static List in a class.
2 load list with data.
3 re-load the list whenever you change the database(Observer pattern)
4 call notifyDatasetChanged() every time you reload the list(in update() of your observer )
note: use endless array adapter